# web reactjs vs .net core Error Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, css-loader

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3crM.png)

I tried:
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
npm install -g sass
npm install --save-dev sass
But it doesn't work, please help me!